# Sketch 3 - Is there a way to export all artboards in a .sketch file from multiple Pages?

Tags: export, sketch-app, artboard

I am using Sketch 3, and I suspect this feature is somewhere in the program, but I'm stuck.

My issue is, I'm unable to export all artboards across all the Pages in my .sketch document.

I have 2 Pages in my .sketch file:
"Branding Elements" Page
"Sign Up Screen" Page

Each page has multiple artboards that I want to export as .pngs, but for some reason I am only able to export the artboards that appear in the "Branding Elements" Page, and not the "Sign Up Screen" Page. The Sign Up artboards don't even show up in the little preview popup window.

Is this a bug, or user error (I am new to Sketch), or a feature that doesn't exist?

Comment: A work-around I found is export as a .pdf, and then using Adobe Acrobat, export the .pdf as .pngs.

Comment: Yes that is the one way Sarah and there is another which is you can select all art boards and make them exportable and then export them. See my answer below

Answer (score 8):

For a single page you can export all artboards at once like this:
**Edit > Select all art boards**
**Layer > Make exportable**
Now you can export art boards.

For example I have four art boards:
[image]

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct.

Comment: The question is about to export artboards **from multiple pages at the same time**... so your answer doesn't solve the problem, because it only works for artboards in the same page.

Comment: "Select all Artboards" doesn't make all artboards in all pages exportable as you described if you have multiple pages.

Comment: @Luciano yes that is true. It export artboards on one page at a time.

Answer (score 1):

- Select all artboards in a page
- Make Exportable
- repeat for all pages
- Select all pages
- Share > Export: this will export all Artboards for all pages.

Answer (score -2):

I haven’t found a solution for that inside the software, but there are some plugins that allow that in PDF format, like [this Sketch plugin for PDF exporting](https://github.com/DWilliames/PDF-export-sketch-plugin).